# Sencha Touch 2 fixed header

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Is there a way to have a fixed non animated header in a sencha app and still retain page animation and browsing history?

I need my header to not animate on a page slide. The way i tried it is:

```
-main container (v box)
--header container
--card container(card layout)
---card
---card2
---card3
```

Etc

And I manually switch the cards inside the card container with `setActiveItem(index)`
The header is never animated in/out but I dont have history now so the only way to have a back button is manually hard coding it with setActiveItwm(prevIndex)

Its an unfortunate and dirty solution maybe somebody else has a better one.

Comment: What do you mean fixed non animated header? Doesn't the navigationview fit your needs? http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I achieved it using sencha architect to test. From memory I created a base container that had layout vbox. Inside that I had a top tabpanel and under that a tabpanel. I then set the flex on the top panel to 0.2 and the tabpanel to 0.8. That way my header will always be 20% height on any device. I hope this helps.

Comment: That is exactly what i described im doing in my originsl question :( was hoping there was a better approach. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You require   [`Ext.navigation.View`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View)

Comment: using Ext.navigation.View, the header always stays in place? or the whole screen changes on a push/pop?

Comment: the header indeed doesnt move but it has no history stack. ill have to find a way to test it out and see if history can be added (android back button uses browser hashtag history)

Answer (score 0):

Use Ext.navigation.View and create basic navigation between views...then hide the navigation view you can do that by making the navigationBar property as hidden:true

Next have a common navigation header as you have mentioned above...
Going forward using a button lets say would be by using

```
button.up('navigationview').push({xtype: 'card2'});
```

This button will be somewhere in your card which takes you to next card

Similarly for going back on button click

```
button.up('navigationview').pop();
button.up('navigationview').pop(2);//Will take you two views back and so on
```

These buttons will be on your common header